# Having problem with opening 2nd page of blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I have a website on blogger and I have posted 7 posts in it.
But, whenever I open my website it shows only 3 posts on my main page and it's not showing 2nd main page.
My website name - www.BlueWOrld.ooo
have a look and please help me to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two orange buttons down. You can see newer/older posts.
/*I cannot post picture because I haven't enough reputations*/